Axios Interceptor to customize header for uuid
import axios, { AxiosInstance } from "axios";
import { v4 as uuidv4 } from 'uuid';


const axiosInstance: AxiosInstance = axios.create({
  baseURL: "http://localhost:8080",
  timeout: 10000, // 10 s
  headers: {
    "Content-Type": "application/json",
  },
});

axiosInstance.interceptors.request.use(config => {
  // Generate a unique correlation ID
  const correlationId = uuidv4();
  
  // Attach the correlation ID to the headers
  if (config.headers) {
    config.headers['X-Correlation-ID'] = correlationId;
  } else {
    config.headers = {
      'corRelationId': correlationId,
    };
  }

  return config;
}, error => {
  return Promise.reject(error);
});

export default axiosInstance;

I'm trying to create corRelationId dynamically send every request but i'm getting error
Error
TS2322: Type '{ corRelationId: string; }' is not assignable to type 'AxiosRequestHeaders'.
Type '{ corRelationId: string; }' is missing the following properties from type 'AxiosHeaders': set, get, has, delete, and 23 more.
19 |     config.headers['X-Correlation-ID'] = correlationId;
20 |   } else {

21 |     config.headers = {
|     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
22 |       'corRelationId': correlationId,
23 |     };
24 |   }


The Axios headers isn't a plan object but why are you trying to set a different header key based on if it exists or not?

AxiosRequestHeaders isn't a plain object which is why TypeScript is complaining. See https://github.com/axios/axios?tab=readme-ov-file#-axiosheaders
It's also never optional so there's no need for your check...

interface InternalAxiosRequestConfig<D = any> extends AxiosRequestConfig<D> {
  headers: AxiosRequestHeaders; //  not optional
}


Simply set the header key / value pair that you want. You should also use the set() method as direct property access is deprecated
// Don't blanket-set content-type headers
const axiosInstance: AxiosInstance = axios.create({
  baseURL: 'http://localhost:8080',
  timeout: 10000, // 10 s
});

axiosInstance.interceptors.request.use((config) => {
  const correlationId = uuidv4();

  config.headers.set('X-Correlation-ID', correlationId);
  return config;
}, null, { synchronous: true });

Some notes:

Don't set default content-type headers for all requests. It's redundant and can easily lead to confusion / mistakes
You can pass null for the 2nd interceptor onRejected parameter to simply use the default
You should set options for { synchronous: true } if your interceptor is synchronous for better optimisation

